# Rounding of negative numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

We have come across a problem with **Math.round()** in JavaScript. The problem is that this function doesn't round correctly for negative numbers. For example :

1.5 ~= 2

0.5 ~= 1

-0.5 ~= 0 // Wrong

-1.5 ~= -1 // Wrong

And this is not correct according to arithmetic rounding. The correct numbers for -0.5 should be -1 and -1.5 should be -2.

**Is there any standard way, to correctly round negative numbers in Javascript ?**

Comment: maybe if it's negative, make it not negative, round it. then just make it negative again?

Comment: why it's wrong, it's round top just exactly on the positive numbers.

Comment: @MoshFeu . . . It's round top on the positive numbers for a reason. The "easy" number theory is that a positive number like 1.5000000000... can never become less than 1.5, only more, like 1.5000000000000000054623... Otherwise it would already be something like 1.49999999999... That's why 1.5 is rounded up to 2. For negative numbers, the logic turns around. A negative number like -1.50000000... can never become more than -1.5, only less, like -1.50000000000000003432.... That's why -1.5 should be rounded down to -2. (IMHO)

Comment: Seems that Java applies the rounding strategy in positive direction as well. So it seems logical that that strategy is adopted by JavaScript. I guess it's something we have to live with.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could save the sign and apply later, in ES5;

```js
function round(v) {
    return (v >= 0 || -1) * Math.round(Math.abs(v));
}

console.log(round(1.5));  //  2
console.log(round(0.5));  //  1
console.log(round(-1.5)); // -2
console.log(round(-0.5)); // -1
```

Comment: Ok, so let's all  do as if it is normal that the round and floor functions in js are returning false results ^^

Comment: Instead of `(v >= 0 || -1)` you can simply use `Math.sign(v)`, making this a very compact one-liner: `Math.sign(v) * Math.round(Math.abs(v));`. In terms of performance, this should run at least as fast, or even faster.

Comment: @Yeti, at this time `Math.sign` wasn't widely available.

Comment: @NinaScholz Wasn't `Math.sign` already available since 2015? Anyway, to avoid CPU-intensive multiplication and type conversion operations, at first sight my initial attempt to implement "regular rounding" would have been to opt for the expression `(v >= 0) ? Math.round(v) : -Math.round(-v)`. Here I consider an expression like `-v` to be equivalent to `0 - v` instead of `(-1) * v`. If I am wrong about that, I would have changed my expression to the more explicit variant `((v >= 0) ? Math.round(v) : (0 - Math.round(0 - v)))`.

Comment: @BartHofland, 1. no. please see above. 2. yes it is possible but contains too much brackets.

Comment: 1. I reread it all, but I still don't understand. According to the info on MDN, the `Math.sign` function should have been around in all major browsers since September 2015 (except maybe for Internet Explorer), while this question seems to be posted in 2017. Am I perhaps missing something else? 2. I agree that there are very many brackets there. I only added them for clarity. Due to operator precedence, they are not necessary. However, your solution is quite nice and compact, and any negative performance impact (if any) is probably negligible in practice. I'll stick with your solution.

Answer (score 24):

Apply [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) after converting to a positive number and finally roll back the sign. Where you can use [`Math.sign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) method to get the sign from the number and [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) to get the absolute of the number.

```
console.log(
  Math.sign(num) * Math.round(Math.sign(num) * num),
  // or
  Math.sign(num) * Math.round(Math.abs(num))
)
```

```js
var nums = [-0.5, 1.5, 3, 3.6, -4.8, -1.3];

nums.forEach(function(num) {
  console.log(
    Math.sign(num) * Math.round(Math.sign(num) * num),
    Math.sign(num) * Math.round(Math.abs(num))
  )
});
```

Answer (score 5):

*ES6* has added a method called **Math.trunc** using which we can get the integer part of a decimal number

> The Math.trunc() function returns the integer part of a number by
> removing any fractional digits.

```
Math.trunc(42.84) -> Returns 42
Math.trunc(5.3) -> Returns 5
Math.trunc(-4.3) -> Returns -4
Math.trunc(-3.123) -> Returns -3
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try using Math.ceil(num) to round num and then - 1 if num was negative, e.g.

```
if (num < 0) {
  num = Math.ceil(num) - 1;
} else {
  num = Math.ceil(num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var r = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
```

---

How about purely evaluating the result without using the math library? eg, by using a ternary operator, you can elegantly check for negative numbers and then floor after "rounding":

```
var n = r + (r < 0 ? -0.5 : 0.5) | 0;
```

The `| 0` is just a silly trick in js that "overloads" the binary operator (you could use any binary operator) in order to truncate the number.

*Note* that this is not flooring (like `Math.floor`), since `Math.floor(-3.2)`, for example, will actually yield `-4`.

---

One could even do something similar to @Balan's answer (I like that one and the one below, but I feel like this or the ternary operator will just be a touch faster--I am probably wrong, though, because the `Math` libraries have been proven to be very fast):

```
var n = (r + Math.sign(r) / 2) | 0;
```

---

probably the fastest, most elegant way:

```
var n = Math.floor(r + 0.5);
```

---

example:

```js
var body = document.getElementById("myTable").children[1];
var i, iMax = 100, r, tr, td;
for (i = 0; i < iMax; i++) {
    r = Math.random() * 200 - 100;
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = r;
    tr.appendChild(td);
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = (r + Math.sign(r) / 2) | 0;
    tr.appendChild(td);
    body.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```css
#myTable {
    min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>float</th>
   <th>round</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rounding with precision.
Rounds to Int by default or, if second argument is provided, to n digits after decimal point.
+ '1' fixes incorrect rounding for .0X5 numbers.

```
function round(num, digits=0) {
    if (!(num % 1)) return num
    return +Number(num + '1').toFixed(digits)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First observe that `Math.round(v)` is defined as `Math.floor(v + 0.5)`:

```js
Math.round(-1.7) === -2
Math.round(-1.3) === -1
Math.floor(-1.7 + 0.5) === -2
Math.floor(-1.3 + 0.5) === -1
```

Then realize that `parseInt(v)` is similar to `Math.floor(v)`, however, it handles negative numbers differently (exactly how you expected it to behave):

```js
Math.floor(1.7) === 1
Math.floor(-1.7) === -2
parseInt(1.7) === 1
parseInt(-1.7) === -1
```

So the `parseInt(v)` behavior is what you want, but instead of flooring, you want rounding. In order to apply this to any number, we need to add `+0.5` for positive numbers, and `-0.5` for negative numbers. So the **solution is this function**:

```js
var parseIntRound = function(v)
{
    return parseInt(v + Math.sign(v)/2);
};
// or with modern syntactic sugar:
// const parseIntRound = v => parseInt(v + Math.sign(v)/2);

parseIntRound( 1.5) ===  2
parseIntRound( 0.5) ===  1
parseIntRound(-0.5) === -1
parseIntRound(-1.3) === -1
parseIntRound(-1.5) === -2
parseIntRound(-1.7) === -2
```

Where `Math.sign(v)` returns 1 for any positive number (>0), -1 for any negative number (<0), and 0 for positive zero (and -0 for negative zero).