# Execl INT for javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula, int

can you know if exist **function excel** `INT()` in **javascript** ?

i don't know if the **equivalent** is

```
    parseInt()
    toFixed()
    floor()
```

*Can you tell me also differences ?*

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Comment: Well you can read here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Comment: But which is the same of INT() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question**

Which JavaScript function will provide the same functionality as the Excel function `INT()`?

**Answer**

`Math.floor(Number);` will round a number down to the nearest whole number.

**Examples**

*Excel -*

```
INT(-8.1) returns -9

INT(8.1) returns 8
```

*JavaScript -*

```
Math.floor(-8.1); returns -9

Math.floor(8.1); returns 8
```

Since your goal is for `-8.1` to return `-9` (as mentioned in the comments) then you are going to want to use,

```
Math.floor(-8.1); // returns -9
```

Comment: but INT for negative number return the integer number more close and low so in js i should to use .floor() ?

Comment: I understand you're having a hard time with English, can you try and illustrate what you are trying to say with an example? Int(x) = X? I would be happy to help you.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to accomplish? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41586933/2218253

Comment: In Excel the function INT(x) if x is negative (for example -8.1) return "-9" so returns the integer number lower and closer to "x" (in this case -9). So in javascript i should use ".floor" to have result like excel INT() even for negative number ?

Comment: Hey @Borja I left for food sorry. I am back now and I read through this again. I believe what you need is `Math.floor(),` yes. `Math.floor(-8.1)` will return -9 as you pointed out which is the the same as `INT(-8.1)`. If this helps answer your question, please mark it has accepted.